# Integrrate Parse cloud with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform

I am using phonegap to build parse cloud..First i tried to build code with my browser and checked in that it works without any errror. But when i copied to eclipse (phonegap) ,

`Parse.Initialize` line is getting error:

**Error:**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Parse is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:36

**MYCODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/parse-1.2.18.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){  
 Parse.initialize("HxxxxxxxxxxxxxmALn","x5qxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxVk");  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you include jQuery twice (which could cause problems)?

Comment: As a best practice, always load code locally, do not use remote libs. Your app will fail if no connection is present.

Comment: @Raptor: Code updated...

Comment: @ Dawson Loudon : Yes, I had loaded the parse.js locally only...But i didn't get , why it still showing "Parse not defined"

Comment: @Raptor:Nope same bug..